# minimum cut off for the microphone's volume with Windows voice recognition

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

I am using Window's voice recognition API, and it keeps detecting very low background noise as the word "if" repetitively. I have been trying to find a way to put a minimum volume requirement for it to start accepting input, but all its members are set to read-only.

How can I set a minimum cut off for the microphone's volume?

Edit: Figured out a way to get the average and ignore the text if it's under the average I want

```
public void hRecognition_AudioStateChanged(object sender, AudioStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AudioState == AudioState.Stopped)
        {
            volumeAverage /= volumeCount;
        }
        else if (e.AudioState == AudioState.Speech)
        {
            volumeAverage = 0;
            volumeCount = 0;
        }
    }

    public void hRecognition_AudioLevelUpdated(object sender, AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        volumeAverage += e.AudioLevel;
        volumeCount += 1;
    }
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with your solution, you can post it as an answer to your own question, just FYI.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Good question, i had to a little work on some sound analyses software. And you could implement a sound filter, [sound filters](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/). I have no experience with windows voice recognition but with i hope this helps, look into signal proccesing simple noise filters